# Google Play release shows that there are 88 localizations but there are actually only 10

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I'm uploading a build to google play, and I just noticed that it says that I have 88 localizations included. In actuality I only have about 10. Just wondering if anyone has run into this issue?

[image: screenshot showing 88 localizations on google play app bundle]

Here are the localizations I have in the project:

[image: shows about 10 values-language folders in the finder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have only 10 localizations in your project but the play store is showing more since for example you have "en" only in the project but play store is showing "en_au","en_ca","en_Gb","en_us" and so on for each language , so its automatically instead of adding only "en = english " its adding english_usa english_australia english_canada english_GreatBritian . As for the errors this might cause i am not if sure it affects the app but i had a similar situation and the app runs without problems on all my implemented localizations

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation. I guess I wasn't looking close enough.

Comment: For example it's visible the "af" localization on the play console screenshot in the question, but here is nothing about the "af" local on the project screenshot. Any idea why that can happen? Thanks.